# What is this data format "5540 6EA5 0709 24DF A45C 5BF3 AE5A 4350 BC40 6988"

Tags: pgp

I am a little baffled, I cannot get my brain into gear to pin point what these data format the following is:

```
5540 6EA5 0709 24DF A45C 5BF3 AE5A 4350 BC40 6988
```

Any ideas ?

**I think the consensus it that the above is a PGP key**

Comment: Seems like a PGP key to me. May I know the context, where did you find this, and what utilization are you aiming at?

Comment: I found it on a business card.

Comment: Then it is PGP key for sure. Was there any QR code in the business card. Basically PGP keys on business cards are used to download vCard using QR Code.

Comment: Added the above comment as answer so that it helps friends while searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found it on a business card, then it is PGP key for sure. Was there any QR code in the business card. Basically PGP keys on business cards are used to download vCard using QR Code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but looks like [Google diverter PGP keys](http://sam.zoy.org/fun/google-diverters/pgp.html)

Answer (score 1):

The data is a base16-encoded 20-byte sequence. While it can be anything, the most likely is an SHA1 *hash* of something (maybe of the PGP key). This is definitely not the key itself, because PGP keys are long (hundreds of bytes). Thus other answers are misleading.